# split string from database column uploaded filenames

Tags: php, mysql, database

i have value from database column like this **["data string 1.xlsx","data string 2.xlsx"]**, how i can echo each element so i want get result like this:

- data string 1.xlsx
- data string 2.xlsx

Thanks

Comment: If you are asking to split comma separated string to rows, then refer this  https://stackoverflow.com/a/17942691/5234334)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL split values to multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942508/sql-split-values-to-multiple-rows)

Comment: Looks like what you have there is actually JSON-encoded data, so [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) would be your easy solution.